# how to check the daemon running status

Tags: daemon, opennms

I am trying to figure out what daemons are running on the Opennms (version 1.12.8) for the purpose of debugging. Is there any good way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the way to check it. Just goto the `/opennms/bin` directory and run

```
sudo ./opennms -v status
```